# Loop repeats despite reaching exit condition

Tags: c++, loops

I have a small program that is attempting to build a right triangle.

The boundaries given by the program are that the base and height must both be in the range [10,20].

The code seems to work just fine for building triangles in the range [10,19].
However, at the boundary conditions of [n,20] or [20,n], the output goes haywire and refuses to exit the for loop that generates the middle of the triangle (between the base and top lines).

I'd appreciate assistance pinpointing the issue, thank you.

I've looked into the issue but I'm out of practice and should be treated as a novice.

The issue is definitely with the while or nested for loop after the "BUILD" comment.

Please note that there may be one or two non relevant vars defined above this block level of code provided.

```
//TRIANGLE// 
 if (shapeselect=2)
 {
 int base;
 int height;
 //prompt use for base measurement//
 cout<<"Please select the size of the BASE of your triangle, in the range [10,20]\n"<<endl;
 cin>>base;
  while (base!=10&&base!=11&&base!=12&&base!=13&&base!=14&&base!=15&&base!=16&&base!=17&&base!=18&&base!=19&&base!=20)
  {
  cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  cout<<"You have entered an invalid value.\nPlease enter a valid value for the BASE of your triangle in the range of [10,20].\n";
  cin>>base;
  }
 //prompt user for height measurement//
 cout<<"Please select the size of the HEIGHT of your triangle, in the range of [10,20].\n";
 cin>>height;
 while (height!=10&&height!=11&&height!=12&&height!=13&&height!=14&&height!=15&&height!=16&&height!=17&&height!=18&&height!=19&&height!=20)
  {
  cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  cout<<"You have entered an invalid value.\nPlease enter a valid value for the HEIGHT of your triangle, in the range [10,20].\n";
  cin>>base;
  }
  //BUILD TRIANGLE//
 string bottom(base, '*');
 string top="*";
 int middlerows=height-1;
 cout<<top<<endl;
  while (middlerows!=1)
  {
   int middlespacechars;
   for (middlespacechars=0; middlespacechars!=base-2; ++middlespacechars)
   {
   string middlespace(middlespacechars, ' ');
   cout<<"*"<<middlespace<<"*\n";
   --middlerows;
   }
  }
 cout<<bottom<<"\n"<<endl;
 cout<<"^TRIANGLE\n";
 cout<<"BASE = "<<base<<endl;
 cout<<"HEIGHT = "<<height<<endl;
 cout<<goodbye<<"\n"<<endl;
 }

}
```

The top of the triangle prints (single "*").
Then the middle portion of the triangle repeats infinitely (asterisks bedded with spaces between).
Counting the rows, it seems that it is reaching the case of base-2 spaces, but not exiting.  It seems to get to line '19/20'.

Comment: What do you think is more readable: the two long expressions that are contained inside those `while` statements, or simply `while (base < 10 || base > 20)` and `while (height < 10 || height > 20)`?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Specifically, does it show you the value `middlerows` inside both loops?

Comment: Also, why do you need a `while`? Won't a `for` loop work here as well?

Comment: Look at this even more, it's probably something to do with putting `--middlerows;` inside your other loop. Your logic not clear to me, but you probably want to rework that. You may only need one loop, even.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it prevents the use of non int character Input without using additional libraries.

Comment: @chipster I did indeed begin with two for loops (one nested), but encountered the same error.  The while was just troubleshooting and it seems I've left it there; I see no functional difference.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The two simple comparisons are completely 100% logically equivalent to the novel that's currently used for the `while` loops.

Comment: Sorry, Sam, were you addressing my commend that was in reply to you, or to chipster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of debugging, it seems that your code breaks for **any input where base != height.**

The issue is in your `for` loop - your logic in the `while` loop that middlerows is supposed to count down from `height-1` until it hits `1` is correct, but in the `for`, you encounter issues if base and height aren't the same - the loop forces middlerows into a negative value, which causes it to miss your escape condition of `middlerows != 1`.

If, for example, the user inputs `11, 15`, then on the first run-through, middlerows will be 14, and the for loop will count from 0 up to up to 9 (height-2), decrementing middlerows each time. At the end of this loop, your middlerows is now 5. `5 != 1`, so the loop will run again.

After running again, middlerows is at -4. `-4 != 1`, so the loop runs again, dropping middlerows to -13... and then it just keeps going down, forever (or until you wrap around and get lucky, somehow perfectly hitting `middlerows=1`).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand why middle rows would decrement by a value greater than one, given "--middlerows".

Comment: The middlerows variable is decremented by one given `--middlerows`, but the for loop does this decreasing **several times in a row.** This causes it to decrement a _cumulative_ value of greater than one, since your code can't check the while loop's condition while it's locked in the for loop.